# How can I change woocommerce_sale_flash from Text to Discount Percentage

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to know what would be the code to change woocommerce_sale_flash from the default text which is "Sale!" to the Discount Percentage you actually are saving.

Just now I have this piece of code which changes the text of the sale flash icon:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'my_custom_sale_flash');
function my_custom_sale_flash($text, $post, $_product) {
return '<span class="onsale"> Discount!</span>';  
}
```

Instead of displaying the same text each time, it should display the actual discount (for example: 25% off) of the product.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try out this :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'my_custom_sale_flash');
function my_custom_sale_flash($text) {
    global $product;
    $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
    return '<span class="onsale">'.$percentage.'%</span>';  
}
```

Comment: Awesome @Rohil_PHPBeginner this one is working fine. How can I make the percentage a two decimal number?

Comment: use this for 2 decimal percentage: `$percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100, 2 );`

Comment: I think that this is ok for simple products or variable product with one main product price. If there are variations with different prices within the product, then one would need to added some extra code logic.